# cURL error on Wamp : error setting certificate verify locations (77)

Tags: php, curl, certificate, wamp

I'm discovering the cURL lib and I'm trying to reach a resource from a data public website.
This is my current **index.php** file:
*<api_key> is voluntary hidden.*

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init('https://cdt.hafas.de/opendata/apiserver/departureBoard?accessId=<api_key>&lang=fr&id=200404001&format=json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'cert.cer');
$data = curl_exec($curl);

if ($data === false){
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);
```

Unfortunately I got this error with Wamp:

```
C:\wamp64\www\am-sn\index.php:7:string 'error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: cert.cer
  CApath: none' (length=77)
```

---

This is what I tried so far:

**1.** Downloaded the certificate from the target website (format X509 - base64) that I renamed to **cert.cer** and placed it in the same folder as my **index.php** file.

**2.** Downloaded file (renamed to **cacert.pem**) from https://curl.se/ca/cacert-2022-07-19.pem and placed it in *"C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.0/extras/ssl/"*

**3.** Went to *"C:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.4.0/"* and edited the **php.ini** file to uncomment those line and set the relative paths:

```
curl.cainfo="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

**4.** Restarted Wamp services and refreshed the page

---

But I still get the error.
Did I do something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: becarfull with windows path in config file did you try : curl.cainfo="C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.0\\extras\\ssl\\cacert.pem"

Comment: the think is not right is you download a pem and suppose like "https://127.0.0.1"  /  "https:// localhost "   is should work : witch is the problem ! you cannot enable ssl for localhost so not the download script is the problem (if they are problems in the script too that later now prior is understand you cannot enable ssl https on localhost  )

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand you answer. You mean the fact localhost doesn't have SSL is a problem? But the guy in the tutorial I watched managed to it with his localhost: https://youtu.be/vq7yJDuf42E?t=796
How did he proceed then?